# r - Taking user input and assiging it with a 'for loop'

Tags: r

I have the following code which takes keywords from the user so that I can search a database of word_vectors:

```
theme_terms = lemmatize_words(scan(strip.white = TRUE, sep = '\n', what = character()))
```

I want to use the words provided in the following assignment, but the user can enter as many words as they like, and my current assignment is unfortunately static.

```
result = word_vectors[theme_terms[1], , drop = F] + word_vectors[theme_terms[2], , drop = F]
```

I want to recreate the above statement in a `for loop` that will take as many words as the user inputs.

I have tried the following:

a) doesnt work as I am trying to bind a non-numeric argument to a binary operator

```
for(i in 1:length(theme_terms)){
  temp =  word_vectors[theme_terms[i], , drop = F] 
  result = result + temp
}
```

b) doesnt work as its a string and I also have to remove string marks and extra + at the end

```
for(i in 1:length(theme_terms)){
  temp = paste0(paste0("word_vectors[", theme_terms[i],", , drop = F] + "))
  result = paste(result, temp)
}
```

Any suggestions? thank you.

edit.

word_vectors is a matrix of values which can be reproduced as follows:

```
terms = c("cancer", "blood", "machine")
v1 = c(0.002, 0.313, 0.1313)
v2 = c(0.23, 0.14, 0.155)
v3 = c(0.141, 0.41, 0.125)

word_vectors = as.matrix(data.frame(terms, v1, v2, v3))
```

Comment: Can you provide some data and make this post reproducible? What is `word_vectors`? Does `sum(sapply(theme_terms, function(x) word_vectors[x, , drop = F]))` work? Also please include all the necessary non-base R libraries which are used in the post.

Comment: Hi Rob, unfortunately not as word_vectors contains vectors of numbers. Essentially I want to replicate result = word_vectors[theme_terms[1], , drop = F] + word_vectors[theme_terms[2], , drop = F]..... (inf) .....let me try and create a reproducible example

Comment: added a example of what word_vectors is. Thank you

Comment: Oh your code does work without the sum part, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sapply` :

```
result <- sapply(theme_terms, function(x) word_vectors[x, , drop = F])
```

Answer (score 1):

With `for` loop we can initialize a `list` for storing the output

```
out <- vector('list', length(theme_terms))
for(i in seq_along(theme_terms)) {
    out[[i]] <- word_vectors[theme_terms[i], , drop = FALSE]
}
```